# How can I use with inside apply in sql server? I know another solution without apply. but can we do with outer apply? if 'yes' then how?

Tags: sql-server, xml, openrowset, outer-apply, with-clause

**Can we use with inside any apply in the SQL server?**
For traversing all nodes in the XML file I am trying to use outer apply so I can traverse in one go.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, Address
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer')
WITH 
(
CustomerID [varchar](50) '@CustomerID',
CustomerName [varchar](100) '@CustomerName',
Address [varchar](100) 'Address'
)
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT OrderDate, OrderID--, Address
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer/Orders/Order')
WITH 
(
OrderDate [varchar](100) '@OrderDate',
OrderID [varchar](100) '@OrderID'
Address [varchar](100) 'Address'
) as Orders
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT Quantity, ProductID--, Address
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer/Orders/Order/OrderDetail')
WITH 
(
Quantity [varchar](100) '@Quantity',
ProductID [varchar](100) '@ProductID'
Address [varchar](100) 'Address'
) as OrderDetail
```

this is the XML file

```
<ROOT>
  <Customers>
    --root/customers/cusomer/orders/order/OrderDetail
    <Customer CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42"/>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</ROOT>
```

and this is how i want my result.

| CustomerID | CustomerName | Address | OrderID | OrderDate | ProductID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | Arshad Ali | Address line 1, 2, 3 | 10248 | 2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 10 | 5 |
| C001 | Arshad Ali | Address line 1, 2, 3 | 10248 | 2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 11 | 12 |
| C001 | Arshad Ali | Address line 1, 2, 3 | 10248 | 2012-07-04 00:00:00.000 | 42 | 10 |

I know another solution without apply. but can we do with outer apply? if 'yes' then how?
I am new with this so please help me.

Comment: sp_xml_preparedocument isn't really recommended (it has all sorts of limits and gotchas), and there's no correlation between your three invocations of OpenXML. Do you have something against using the modern [.nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [.value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) syntax?

Comment: I am new to this so what else should I use, I just started with basics and I don't have enough knowledge to implement it so if there is any other way also I would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can choose to go the deepest level and then "crawl up" from it.

```sql
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = N'<ROOT>
  <Customers>
    --root/customers/cusomer/orders/order/OrderDetail
    <Customer CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42"/>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</ROOT>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


select *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer/Orders/Order/OrderDetail')
WITH
    (
        CustomerID      NVARCHAR(30)    '../../../../Customer/@CustomerID'
    ,   CustomerName    NVARCHAR(100)   '../../../../Customer/@CustomerName'
    ,   Address         NVARCHAR(100)   '../../../Address'
    ,   OrderID         NVARCHAR(30)    '../@OrderID'
    ,   OrderDate       DATETIME    '../@OrderDate'
    ,   ProductID       INT '@ProductID'
    ,   Quantity        INT '@Quantity'

    )
    
exec sp_xml_removedocument  @hDoc OUTPUT -- Always clean up your XMLs!
```

Edit #2: "real" apply version:

```sql
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT  @XML = N'<ROOT>
  <Customers>
    --root/customers/cusomer/orders/order/OrderDetail
    <Customer CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11"/>
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42"/>
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</ROOT>'


SELECT  cu.value('@CustomerName', 'nvarchar(1000)') name
,   cu.value('@CustomerID', 'nvarchar(100)') id
,   cu.value('Address[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') address
,   oo.value('@OrderDate', 'datetime') orderdate
,   oo.value('@OrderID', 'varchar(30)') orderid
,   ood.value('@Quantity', 'int') qty
,   ood.value('@ProductID', 'varchar(10)') productId
FROM    (
    SELECT  @xml AS x
    ) xml
OUTER APPLY x.nodes('ROOT/Customers/Customer') c(cu)
OUTER APPLY cu.nodes('Orders/Order') o(oo)
OUTER APPLY oo.nodes('OrderDetail') od(ood)
```

Comment: Appreciate the efforts and time you put into this but as I mentioned, I know this approach I just wanted to know whether we can do it with outer apply if yes then how?

Comment: Made an edit with another version. But maybe you mean apply as in xml.nodes?

Comment: here is the problem if it has only one customer detail is there then it works fine but more than that it is mixing up the data and finding a cross with each field.

Comment: Ok, i edited in another version with "real" XML APPLYs

Comment: This will work, thank you