# Query to shred XML without CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logic, xmldatasource

I have the following XML:

```
DECLARE @Temp XML = 
'<SurveyQLADetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FirstName>Jacal</FirstName>
    <LastName>Duardo</LastName>
    <PhoneNumber>7868256998</PhoneNumber>
    <Email>Duardo</Email>
    <SFId>00Q6R00001XWHWHUA5</SFId>
    <ClubNumber>7446</ClubNumber>
    <QLAList>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>1</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>2</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">Gain strength</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Fitness_Goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>2</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Achieve_Fitness_Goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>3</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>9</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">3-6 months</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Timeline_achieve_goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>4</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Personal_Trainer</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>5</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>15</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">Health reasons (doctor recommendation)</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Motivation_achieving_goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>6</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>19</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">3</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Importance_Goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>7</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>29</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">6 months or more</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Length__thought_goals</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>8</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Anything_stopping_you_from_starting</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>8.1</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Support_friends_family</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>9</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>38</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">3+ per week</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Gym_Visits</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>10</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>42</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">Evening</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>What_time_of_the_day</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>11</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Visit_other_locations</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>12</QuestionId>
            <OptionId>46</OptionId>
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:string">HIIT or small group training</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Amenities_Important</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>13</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Nutrition_Plan</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>14</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <AnswerName xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</AnswerName>
            <QuestionsTypeName>Meal_Plan</QuestionsTypeName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
        <QLADetailsModel>
            <QuestionId>15</QuestionId>
            <OptionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <OtherAnswerName>
                <OtherAnswerDetails>
                    <FriendsName>t</FriendsName>
                    <FriendsPhoneNo>t</FriendsPhoneNo>
                </OtherAnswerDetails>
                <OtherAnswerDetails>
                    <FriendsName>t</FriendsName>
                    <FriendsPhoneNo>t</FriendsPhoneNo>
                </OtherAnswerDetails>
            </OtherAnswerName>
        </QLADetailsModel>
    </QLAList>
</SurveyQLADetails>'
```

I want output as below without using `CROSS APPLY` on SQL Server.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lxA.png)

I have tried below query it shows the same output but I don't want to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.l.value('(FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS FirstName,
    s.l.value('(LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS LastName,
    s.l.value('(PhoneNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS PhoneNumber,
    s.l.value('(Email/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS Email,
    s.l.value('(SFId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS SFId,
    s.l.value('(ClubNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ClubNumber,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OptionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OptionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./AnswerName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS AnswerName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsPhoneNo)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsPhoneNo,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionsTypeName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionsTypeName
FROM @Temp.nodes('(/SurveyQLADetails/QLAList/QLADetailsModel)') AS QLAList(QLADetailsModel)
CROSS APPLY @Temp.nodes('/SurveyQLADetails') s(l)
```

[Output that I want without using CROSS APPLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhqjv.png)

Is there any query that does not use `WHERE` and does not use `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: What's the problem with `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You can use openxml to do this. I answered similar question a while ago to another guy who had cross apply allergy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428144/how-can-i-use-with-inside-apply-in-sql-server-i-know-another-solution-without-a/74434561#74434561

Comment: Yes, you _could_ use `OPENXML` for this, but don't. It's not set-based and leaks resources when you forget to invoke `sp_xml_removedocument` (as 90% of the Microsoft examples tend to do).

Comment: I don't see a difference between your two screen shots. The invocations of `@Temp.nodes()` as you have them are not correlated, they're independent, so is your problem with `CROSS APPLY` that it multiplies the result set when there are multiple `/SurveyQLADetails` elements?

Comment: there is no problem with CROSS APPLY but my ma'am said there's another way to get the same output without CROSS APPLY and she gave me a hint like you can use SELECT inside the SELECT .. like SELECT COL1 , COL2 , SELECT() .. FROM ... i tried but don't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
SELECT 
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS FirstName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS LastName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/PhoneNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS PhoneNumber,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/Email/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS Email,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/SFId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS SFId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(/SurveyQLADetails/ClubNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ClubNumber,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OptionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OptionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./AnswerName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS AnswerName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsPhoneNo)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsPhoneNo,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionsTypeName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionsTypeName
FROM @Temp.nodes('(/SurveyQLADetails/QLAList/QLADetailsModel)') AS QLAList(QLADetailsModel)
```

I'd probably be more minded to do it as below though so at least the `CROSS APPLY` is building on the previous `nodes` result. This lack of any correlation may well be why your colleague is not keen on your current usage.

```
SELECT 
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./FirstName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS FirstName,
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./LastName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS LastName,
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./PhoneNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS PhoneNumber,
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./Email/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS Email,
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./SFId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS SFId,
    SurveyQLADetails.SurveyQLADetailsModel.value('(./ClubNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ClubNumber,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OptionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS OptionId,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./AnswerName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS AnswerName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsName,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./OtherAnswerName/OtherAnswerDetails/FriendsPhoneNo)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS FriendsPhoneNo,
    QLAList.QLADetailsModel.value('(./QuestionsTypeName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS QuestionsTypeName
FROM @Temp.nodes('(/SurveyQLADetails)') AS SurveyQLADetails(SurveyQLADetailsModel)
CROSS APPLY SurveyQLADetailsModel.nodes('QLAList/QLADetailsModel') QLAList(QLADetailsModel)
```